# What is the difference between writeToFile and writeToURL?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Maybe some one can explain that over here or send to me to right docs?

I've read the IOS docs, and Still can't get it, when do i use the writeToURL method. Maybe The problem is with me, if every else but me understand this, but if someone can help me with that, I would be very thankful :-)

Comment: The difference is that writeToFile: needs an NSString and writeToURL: needs an NSURL. Apple recommends you use writeToURL:.

Comment: OK, I will make my question more clear, Maybe stupid, but not that stupid. I understand the name, But is a get it, It is not a HTML URL, right? it is a local URL to a local file on the device, just a deferment way to get to the same data with both methods? Am i right? I do not need to give the URL, i get is the same way i get the path to the file, with the API methods, just another way... Or am i wrong with something? If i am right, why is there the file and the URL methods? why did they add the URL ones? This is the source of my confusion with this issue. Thanks, Erez

Comment: URLs can be both remote and local. You can use `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Comment: Thank you, why didn't you post it as an answer, I think that it might interest many beginners as you see it all over there place, but there is not too much doc about what does things like that mean, and to find it over the web is not that trivial. You can get into the IOS Docs, YES. you can read the API's, YES, but many things like that are not trivial for new programmers and unless someone explaind them to you somewhere it is very hard to find the right answers :-) Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that writeToFile: needs an NSString and writeToURL: needs an NSURL. Apple recommends you use writeToURL:.

URLs can be both remote and local. You can use +[NSURL fileURLWithPath:].

Comment: while URLs can be both remote and local, i don't think you can write to a remote URL.  does anyone know differently?

Comment: if you can't write to a remote URL then why do you need both, file and URL? why what the URL invented anyways? If i am getting the file path from a SDK method anyway why do i need two methods to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

"Since at present only file:// URLs are supported, there is no difference between this method and writeToFile:atomically:, except for the type of the first argument."

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToURL:atomically: