# uploadTaskWithRequest background session fromFile crash

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app using swift 2 and I need to upload photos and videos on my server in background session. For that reason, I write this code :

```
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(SessionProperties.identifier)
        //let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();

        let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

        // To limit to 1 upload at a time

        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        let backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: queue)

        for postingFile in postingFileList {

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: NetworkUtil().serverUrl+"/upload/upload/v1.0/events/\(postingFile.event.id)/files/\(postingFile.file.id)?frag-start=0&frag-size=\(postingFile.fileSize)")!)

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")

            let uploadTask = backgroundSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: postingFile.url)

            //let uploadTask = backgroundSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: postingFile.url, completionHandler: { (NSData, NSURLResponse, NSError) in
            //    print("completion handler")
            //})

            uploadTask.resume()
        }
```

This code crash at line :

```
            let uploadTask = backgroundSession.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: postingFile.url)
```

It says :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot read file at file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0361.JPG'

If I do not use background session, and use this configuration instead :

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
```

there is no crash and upload is done.

Do you have any idea of what happen here with background session using from file?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permission issue. You are trying to access a non sandboxed file URL from a background process. Try moving the file locally to your sandbox directory and then upload in background.

Comment: That's exactly what it was for me although my error was different.  Try using one of the two methods there to move to your Documents directory in you sandbox.  Either of these two may be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761321/what-is-the-difference-between-writetofile-and-writetourl